# azure acs error ID 1113 The specified acs service namespace and management key combination is invalid

Tags: azure, asp.net-4.5

I am getting the error even when I gave correct management Service Key

```
error ID 1113 The specified acs service namespace ' xyz 'and management key combination is invalid
```

[image]

I am using VS2012

Comment: make sure you take the key from "Administration" -> "Management servie" -> "ManagementClient" -> "Symmetric Key"; and not from "Service Settings" -> "Certificates and keys"

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you find a solution to your problem? I've noticed if I use another ACS account, a newer one, it works just fine

Answer (score 2):

In ACS, you have keys for signing tokens and keys for authenticating when administrating your ACS namespace. The one you need to use when using the Identity and Access tool is the key for administration tasks. This is the **management key**, or management service credential, and it's found by doing the following:

1. Login to the ACS portal, then click on  **Management service** under **Administration** from the left nav.
2. Under **Management Service Accounts**, click **ManagementClient** (the default management service account).
3. On the **Edit Management Service Account** page, under **Credentials** click **Symmetric Key**.
4. On the **Edit Management Credential** page, grab the key as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you dont use the new Management Portal to create ACS Namespace. Also your namespace should not end with "-sb" which happens automatically if you create a new ServiceBus. Refer to http://acs.codeplex.com/discussions/402589#post941177 for further details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS2012, it doesn't work. Use password instead of Symmetric key. Check [this](http://tapanila.net/windows-azure-active-directory-access-control-with-visual-studio-2012/)